# How to collect Google Analytics Demographic data from ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3, demographics

I'm Using [This ionic plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/google-analytics/) to collect analytcis from my ionic 3 app, i'm able to get data in analytcis console, except the demographgics data.

According the docs i had set

```
this.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-xxxxxx-x')
    .then((res) => {
      this.ga.setAllowIDFACollection(true)
        .then((res) =>{console.log(res)}) //this returns true
        .catch(e=>{console.log(e)})
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics == '+ e));
```

on tracker ready and its returing a promise value with `true` and in analytcis admin i had enabled the **Enable Demographics and Interest Reports**  but still i'm not getting any data, this was doing in developemnt mode.

can any one tell me how can i get this data.

Answer (score 0):

As per the closed issue on the plugin's github, it needs enough sample of data before it could generate the report. It is also stated by  [Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en) under **Data thresholds**.

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a report, then data for the male value may be withheld.
>
> These thresholds are system defined, and you cannot adjust them.
>
> If a threshold has been applied to a report, you will see a notice below the report title.

Please refer to the github issue:
[Github Issue](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/276)